# How can the speed of nested arrays in Julia be improved?

Tags: arrays, nested, julia

The following function `nested_arrays` generates (surprisingly) a nested array of "depth" `n`. However, when running with even small values of `n` (`2`, `3`, etc.), it takes a reasonably long time to run and display the output.

```
julia> nested_arrays(n) = n == 1 ? [1] : [nested_arrays(n - 1)]
nested_arrays (generic function with 1 method)

julia> nested_arrays(1)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> nested_arrays(2)
1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]

julia> nested_arrays(3)
1-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}:
 Array{Int64,1}[[1]]

julia> nested_arrays(10)
1-element Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}:
 Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}[Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[Array{Int64,1}[[1]]]]]]]]]
```

Interestingly, when using the `@time` macro or a `;` at the end of the line, the result is taking relatively little of the time to calculate. Instead, the actual *displaying* of the result in the REPL takes the majority of the time.

This strange behavior is not shown in, for example, Python.

```
In [1]: def nested_lists(n):
   ...:     if n == 1:
   ...:         return [1]
   ...:     return [nested_lists(n - 1)]
   ...: 

In [2]: nested_lists(10)
Out[2]: [[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]

In [3]: %time nested_lists(100)
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 37.7 µs
Out[3]: [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Why is this function so slow in Julia? Is Julia recompiling the `display` function for different types `T` in `Array{T, 1}`? If so, why is this?

Can the speed of this code be improved, or should this just not be done in Julia? My main concern for this in a practical sense would be, for example, loading a complex, nested JSON file, where simply using an `n`-dimensional array would not be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely due to compilation time.  You can see this by `@time`-ing the `display`.  The second time you display it is fast:

```
julia> nested_arrays(n) = n == 1 ? [1] : [nested_arrays(n - 1)]
nested_arrays (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time display(nested_arrays(15));
1-element Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}:
 Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}[Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[Array{Int64,1}[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
 11.682721 seconds (8.83 M allocations: 371.698 MB, 1.82% gc time)

julia> @time display(nested_arrays(15));
1-element Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}:
 Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1}[Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}[Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[Array{Int64,1}[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
  0.001688 seconds (2.38 k allocations: 102.766 KB)
```

So why is this so slow?  The display here recursively walks through all the arrays and prints them nested inside each other. This is recursively calling `show` with 14 different types — one with 14 nested arrays, then its element with 13 nested arrays, then its element with 12… and so on! Each of those `show` methods gets independently compiled.  Compiling specialized methods for specific element types is a key part of how Julia is able to produce very efficient code. It means that it's able to specialize every single operation done on each element without any runtime type checking or dispatch. Unfortunately in this case, it gets in the way.

You can work around this with an `Any[]` array; in the context of a JSON file this makes quite a lot of sense since you don't know if it'll contain strings or arrays or numbers, etc. This is much faster since it only needs to compile the show method for an `Any[]` array once, and then it recursively uses it.

```
# new session
julia> nested_arrays(n) = n == 1 ? Any[1] : Any[nested_arrays(n - 1)]
nested_arrays (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time display(nested_arrays(15));
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
  1.571632 seconds (767.12 k allocations: 32.472 MB, 1.04% gc time)

julia> @time display(nested_arrays(15));
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
  0.000606 seconds (839 allocations: 30.859 KB)

julia> @time display(nested_arrays(100));
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[Any[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
  0.002523 seconds (17.76 k allocations: 579.297 KB)
```

Comment: I would add that this is an example where Julia's tendency to compile specialized versions of functions – which typically makes Julia fast – is wrong: it would be better to just compile a single, slow, generic version of the show function for arrays. Python always does this and in this case it happens be the right thing to do. In the future, specialization heuristics can easily be made smarter without changing any language semantics.